# x509 validation fails before it can be captured

Tags: spring, security, x509

I have a Spring Boot application, using x509 authentication which further validates users against a database. When a user accesses the site, internal Spring code calls the loadUserByUsername method which in turn makes the database call. This all happens before the controller is aware anything is happening. If the user is not found it throws an EntityNotFoundException and displays the stack trace on the user's browser.

I'm using Spring Boot Starter. The controller has code to capture the exception and return a 'Not Authorized' message, but this happens long before. Has anyone else seen this and do you have a workaround?

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String dn) {
        ApprovedUser details = auService.getOne(dn);
        if (details ==  null){
            String message = "User not authorized: " + dn;
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message);
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        if (details.isAdminUser()){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN_USER"));
        }
        return new AppUser(dn, "", authorities);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use a `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to encapsulate logic that's triggered by an `AuthenticationException`. The `X509AuthenticationFilter` would usually call `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate, which would in turn invoke the `loadUserByUsername(...)` method from `UserDetailsService`. Any `AuthenticationException` thrown by the `UserDetailsService` is caught by the filter and control is passed to the registered `AuthenticationFailureHandler`. This includes `UsernameNotFoundException`.

**However**, if you're using the `X509Configurer`, (`http.x509()`) there is no way of setting a handler directly on the filter. So once the exception is thrown, `X509AuthenticationFilter` catches it, sees that there's no default handler, and then simply passes the request to the next filter in the filter chain.

One way to get around this could be to provide a custom `X509AuthenticationFilter`.

In `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler customFailureHandler;

@Autowired
private UserService customUserService;

@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
} 

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.x509().x509AuthenticationFilter(myX509Filter())
    .userDetailsService(customUserService)
    ...
}

private X509AuthenticationFilter myX509Filter() {
    X509AuthenticationFilter myCustomFilter = new X509AuthenticationFilter();
    myCustomFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    ...
    myCustomFilter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
    myCustomFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customFailureHandler);
    return myCustomFilter;
}
```

Then you can write your own `AuthenticationFailureHandler` implementation and expose it as a bean.